# How should we handle answers that contain little or no user content?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answers copied from an external source](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/answers-copied-from-an-external-source)

I have encountered numerous answers in my perusal of this site that contain at most a sentence or two of user generated content with a quote that is nearly a page of text.

What should we do with these answers?

Comment: See also the more [recent discussion on this topic](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5687/21576).

Answer (score 6):

I firmly believe that as users we should comment on and flag these answers. If they are not improved in a relatively short amount of time (12-24 hours). They should be deleted.

These answers add no value to this site and some of them may actually violate copyright law.

This site is about user content, we of course need links and quotations here, but if you don't have anything to add to the quote then link it in a comment or add it to an existing answer that it supports. Don't just post a quote and not say anything, thats really not useful.

Comment: Agreed, your notes help too.

Answer (score -3):

What is the page of text? is it scripture or is it external source? If it's an external source I would suggest that we flag it.

If it's scripture, well.. Sometimes scripture answers our questions exactly.

Comment: Nobody is objecting to scripture-as-answers. This is actually a duplicate thread, see [Answers copied from an external source](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/154) for some examples of the kinds of answers that are being cited as non-productive.

Answer (score -3):

I completely disagree with you on this one. It's been said repeatedly that this is a question and answer site about Christianity not a discussion site. Downvoting or flagging posts that only contain scripture is not constructive. Often Scripture is clear in matters and dosen't need further commentary, as that is where we dive into discussions that have to do with the doctrines of certain sects. So you can't have it both ways, it's either a Q&A site about Christianity or it's a commentary site. As far as copyright law, several translations are public domain, but most have an acceptable quoting policy.

Comment: See my comment above but this is not about scripture at all.